# What would be the valid syntax for this piece of code?

Tags: python, flask, flask-session

```
@app.route("/login",methods=["POST","GET"])
def login():
if request.method == 'POST':
session.pop('user_id',none)
userrnam = request.form.get("username")
palavrapass= request.form.get("password")

usere = users.query.filter_by(username=userrnam).first()
if usere and palavrapass == usere.password:
    session.['User_id'] = usere.id
    return redirect(url_for('profile'))
pass
return render_template("login.html")
```

> When I run the program, it tells me that this line of code

`session.['User_id'] = usere.id`

> is invalid syntax. If this is wrong syntax, than which is the correct way?

Comment: Remove the `.`. `session['User_id'] = usere.id ` 

Take a look at https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: Sir, have my kids.